# Question about exact sequence of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

Let $R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism, i e. $S$ is a $R$-algebra. If $L,M,N$ are $S$-modules, they are automatically $R$-modules too. If I know that $0\to L\to M\to N\to 0$ is an exact sequence of $S$-modules, can I deduce that it is exact as a sequence of $R$-modules? Or the viceversa?

Comment: Exact as $S$-modules implies exact as $R$-modules because all the maps in the sequence are also $R$-module maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that exactness is defined in purely set theoretic terms: the image of one map is the preimage of 0 along another map. So if you are given a sequence of $S$-modules, it is exact if and only if it is exact as sequence of $R$-modules. But for this to hold, you necessarily have to know that you started with a sequence of $S$-modules, since an $R$-linear map of $S$-modules need not be $S$-linear!

Comment: Thanks. Does this imply that if $M$ is flat as $S$-module it is also flat as $R$-module?

Comment: I think this is a different question, since given an $S$-module $X$ the tensor products $X\otimes_R M$ and $X \otimes_S M$ are distinct in general. I don’t know from the top of my head whether your desired claim is true though, something tells me you would need $S$ to be a faithfully flat $R$-algebra for this to happen.